# "RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable" while adding new route?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, sles12

There is a SLES12 with 10.2.64.x IP.

I want to add an additional one, a 10.2.50.x IP.

Before, the routing looks like this:

```
SERVER:~ # netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.2.64.1       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 foo
10.2.64.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 foo
...
SERVER:~ #
```

Then I am bringing up the new 10.2.50.x IP:

```
SERVER:~ # ifup foo2
foo2       up
SERVER:~ #
```

Then the routing looks like this:

```
SERVER:~ # netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.2.64.1       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 foo
10.2.50.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 foo2
10.2.64.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 foo
...
SERVER:~ #
```

So looks like the 10.2.50.0 packets would go in a wrong direction (???), so I delete that:

```
SERVER:~ # ip route del 10.2.50.0/24 via 0.0.0.0 dev foo2
SERVER:~ #
```

And then I am trying to add the good routing entry (at least AFAIK):

```
SERVER:~ # ip route add 10.2.50.0/24 via 10.2.50.1 dev foo2
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
SERVER:~ #
SERVER:~ # ping -c 1 -w 1 10.2.50.1|grep loss
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
SERVER:~ # ifdown foo2
SERVER:~ #
```

But I got "RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable".

**The Q**: what am I missing? Why can't I add the proper routing entry?

Additionally, while the foo2 is UP, I cannot ping the 10.2.64.x IP.

I am not a networking guy. Just want that there would be these two IPs with correct routing :)